Is it OK to power the circuit while the programmer is connected?
I have an Atmega328 connected to an Olimex AVR programmer, and programming it works fine. Because the programmer does not supply a constant power, I also power the entire circuit from an Arduino (just to have a simple available +5V; I don't use anything else on the board). Both are connected to the same laptop using USB, so I'd reckon the +5V and GND are the same.

I can now program the Atmega and after programming, it runs, so from a developer standpoint I am happy (no need to plug/unplug the programmer each time).
The question now: is this smart or will this fry either the chip, or the programmer?

What does the programmer manual say? Do you have the schematics for it? Even if the USB ports come from same laptop, it might not be wise to short them together, you don't know if they even come from the same 5V source.

Nothing should happen. But to be on the safe side you should use one power supply. Simply power the whole circuit from the programmer or from Arduino (only programmer GND is needed to be connected to Arduino GND). What is the point of using two power supplies?

@G36 the programmer only supplies power when programming.

@Justme the documentation doesn't say much about it.

@BartFriederichs Are you sure? To me the linked documentation says that the programmer is powered from target, and it is incapable of powering the target. So are you sure the programmer can power the target alone? Or that it does not do it by accident? Cheap hobbyist grade programmers of that vintage may be quirky. Also some Olimex programmers that do contain schematics have jumpers inside for different modes of operation.

@Justme where does it say that it powers from target (I only find it is powered by USB). Or should I read V_Tar is being an input pin? Because that would mean what I am doing is correct.

@BartFriederichs It says it supports target voltages between 1.8V to 5.5V. So how can it power the target with some volage if it does not know what target voltage it should use? The point of the target supply wire is to allow for the programmer to use the same voltage as the target already uses. Manual also does not say it powers the target but you might experience this effect due to leakage currents.

@Justme Thanks. It all explains a lot.

I think it's better to disconnect.

The manual of your programmer indicates it needs VREF supply reference from target, and if there are fails it tells you to check the target board supply.
Now, this basically means you should power the target board separately.
If it works without target powered, simply from the programmer, it likely means the programmer powers the target via IO pin buffer leakage current. That is usually not what you want, but it may be enough to power up and program the AVR if nothing else consumes current.
